# Correct Regex-Syntax for re.sub replacement in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm currently looking for the correct regex to replace something like this in Python:

old_string contains:

```
some text
some text
<!-V
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat
V->
some text
```

What I've tried to replace the `<!-V *** V->` part:

```
import re
new_string = re.sub(r"<!-V(.*?)V->", '', old_string)
```

But it seems not correct, maybe anyone can help me with the correct regex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, `.` doesn't match a line break character. If you want `.` to match those too, use the [`DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag:

```
new_string = re.sub(r"<!-V(.*?)V->", '', old_string, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

There's also the option of replacing `.` with a character class that matches everything, by combining two complementary character classes:

```
[\s\S]
```

Comment: I never even thought of the complementary character class solution; that's a handy trick.